# What does “welded” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

What does “welded” mean in this context?

> I hope aged 98 she has both boobs out. Brand new boobs, newly **welded** nipples pointing upwards like Pekinese dogs sniffing chocolate. Give the world something genuine to quack about.

Source: "[Ducks force-fed shortbread, teens drunk on cider, petrol vigilantes... that's the real countryside, Danny Boyle](http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/commentators/grace-dent-ducks-force-fed-shortbread-teens-drunk-on-cider-petrol-vigilantes-thats-the-real-7844861.html)" by Grace Dent, in *The Independent,* June 13, 2012.

Comment: I added a link to the original article. This helps people write good answers. Without this information, often native speakers can't figure these things, either, at least not with confidence. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700) for more about how you can provide this kind of information yourself in your own questions.

Comment: Did your your English dictionary provide a definition of the verb _"to weld"_? How might one of those definitions apply to action upon human flesh? Remember, writers often use words _metaphorically_. (I should think the first sentence much more indecipherable to a new student of English!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence uses the [ordinary meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weld#Etymology_2) of **welded** playfully or metaphorically, to suggest that getting [breast augmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breast_augmentation) surgery would involve [arc welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_welding) new nipples onto Madonna's breasts, like this:

[image: Welding a new nipple onto Madonna]

A clue to the meaning here is that the text comes from a celebrity gossip column. This kind of writing often uses language playfully like this, especially regarding "racy" topics.

Comment: This is great! Now let's see you tackle _**"I hope aged 98 she has both boobs out"**_!

Comment: A better clue would be to Google "madonna steel bra": don't forget, The Material Girl used [just such an item](http://ris.fashion.telegraph.co.uk/RichImageService.svc/imagecontent/1/TMG10357764/m/1bra_2693485a_2694335a.jpg) in her costume.